Solscan doesn’t show token name and logo
This is pump.fun launches token
https://pump.fun/8KDsEUE3NdafcCVPqKrMrPfqh3oT4FzcxsYjwbMqpump
On Solscan it’s not showing token name and logo which is weird.
Ca : 8KDsEUE3NdafcCVPqKrMrPfqh3oT4FzcxsYjwbMqpump
Ticker : onigchi
Name : onigchi
In solscan it shows as SPL TOKEN
tried to reachout solscan via email but no response as well

This maybe caused due to Solscan's filtering of offensive words (racist). In this case it seems incorrectly flagged.
Solana.FM is showing it correctly
Solscan is showing it correctly in the Window title.
The metadata is also error free.


So what’s solution here ? Solscan isn’t responding to any mail also. We are kinda stuck without their support.

Did you try the Telegram group? t.me/SolscanOfficialChat

Is that official chat ?

Just heard back from Solscan. They do not have an official Telegram group
